# Is there a way to browse from random topic to random topic?

Tags: support, questions

I am completely new here and I am overwhelmed. This is a wonderful ocean of information both on and in between the lines.

Is there be a way to leap from random topic to random topic? I usually implement a page that does that on my sites and it would be great to have something like that to navigate through this Pool of Wisdom too. Just F5 and -poof- another topic.

It would be a great help to get a feeling for this place and its companions for newbies like me.

---

Thank you all for what you showed me in this humble first post of mine in this community.

*The need for the random button subsided once I found the power of the tag-button filters*.

What I will never forget, is what I found out about this Q&A site. It is very healthy. I undeliberately and very hesitantly injected this off-topic question on Stack Overflow and within 5 minutes, I was shoved this way by five sober and friendly white blood cells. The Organism is very strong and decisive on staying healthy.

This simple post is one that I'll never forget. I feel welcome here, and should I do anything wrong, I have every confidence that I'll be standing corrected in no time, so false habits won't get a chance to creep in.

I greet you, and thank you for this warm welcome.

Comment: A "random question" button like Wikipedia would be great, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5551/random-question-button

Comment: Now random has his own tag, too ;)

Comment: I am shocked and apalled that you haven't gotten your name changed to Rofl.  I mean, is nothing sacred anymore?

Comment: [Edit Overflow](http://pmortensen.eu/) has it (currently Windows only): menu *Browse* -> *Open Random Post*.

Answer (score 7):

I expect attempts to move this question to Meta Stackoverflow.

The best way to leap from random topic to random topic is just to look at the newest questions. They're a pretty random selection of topics, although (of course) favourite topics predominate.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are no bonus points for bringing in new users.

The closest thing to a random question section would be the newest questions. It is the most random of any of the question sorting options.  Recent questions and active questions are also good sources.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from just refreshing the new questions page. I am sure someone like Sampson or one of our other Greasemonkey gurus could work up something to bring back a random question.

Comment: A random content page is also a great place to redirect a 401 etc to. 

Suppose i'd want such a page so badly i'd be happy to build it myself, how would i go on about that? It's uttelry simple Php and a bit of mySql, even a web-n00b like me can easily do it. 

Because there's lots to be found underneath those layers of dust.