# Are edited questions no longer bumped to the front page?

Tags: support, edits, bump

I've tried editing a couple of questions of mine to get them bumped to the front page - one of them quite substantially. Nothing happened.

Does editing no longer have this side-effect?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The front page is "aggressively cached". Wait 60 seconds then check again.

Some notes:

- Questions with a sufficiently negative score will not be bumped.
- If there has been a significant amount of activity, your edited post may end up off the first page, even after being bumped to the top of the queue.

Comment: Also note that questions with sufficiently low score won't show up on the front page even when edited. And that if you're simply unlucky, enough other activity has occurred that your question has rolled off the page. For example, romkyn's last edit was 9m ago, but the front page only goes up to 8m.

Comment: @Grace oh right, it's probably the low score then. Thanks! (I guess I'll have to wait until I can give bounty for that one to get visibility... if only I could do it straight away :D)

Comment: @Grace. Edited. CW'd. Thanks for your partiipation :)

Comment: The negative score threshold is -4 or less on Stack Overflow and the new SE2.0 sites. I do not know about Server Fault and Super User (I expect -4), and on Meta it is -8.