# Bump the Question Up !

Tags: discussion, questions, bump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

Stack Overflow doesn't provide a facility to rethrow the same question.

It can only be rolled back!

Shouldn't there be the facility to re-throw the same question to the top for a limited number of times? There can be a condition that if the question is not being answered or if it gets a minimum of 3 votes then it can be rethrown!

EDIT :
Yes, it is just the bump facility, I was talkin about.
Well, editing or any other changing and make it to bump should not be the only way.

Users should also have a bump facility at some condition.

Comment: What does "rethrow" mean exactly?

Comment: Oh look! It's the guy who rolledback his question about 4 times so that my answer gets bumped up to something like +50! I've never really got the chance to say thanks for all the rep I got...

Answer (score 7):

I guess you mean to bring the question back on the front page. All you need to do is make a sensible edit. Actually any edit or retag will do, but enhancing the question with more detail will earn you more respect and probability to receive answers. Most the time they will be bumped to the front page.

Too many edits will result in the post turning community wiki. Also too many edits and rollbacks are regarded offensive by moderators.

There have been [many questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bump) regarding this.

Sometimes that [will not work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62261/are-edited-questions-no-longer-bumped-to-the-front-page), especially when a question has low reputation value.

Adding an answer will also rebump the question. Just make sure that it is an answer, not a refinement of the question, as this is a Q&A and no forum.

And there is always the user driven bump giving a bounty.

Comment: Also, the Community♦ user will occasionally (and confusingly) bump random "unanswered" - unaccepted with no answers having more than two votes - questions.

Comment: Also note that a sufficient number of senseless edits or roll backs will be construed as cheating and may bring a warning from the moderators. What's a sufficient number? Well...dozens is certainly enough, but it really depends on what you're doing with those edits.