# Does community user bump also closed question and low score questions?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, community-user, bump

One of the thing [Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) does is bumping old unanswered questions.

Does this include closed questions? If a question has no upvoted answers (or even no answers at all) and the question has been closed for some reason, will such question be bumped by Community user?

I have also found out that questions that have enough downvotes are [not bumped by edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62261/are-edited-questions-no-longer-bumped-to-the-front-page/62262#62262). Are unanswered questions with low score still poked by the Community user?

Comment: I'm gonna go with "no" on the closed questions, at least it shouldn't do that. What makes you ask?

Comment: @Stijn I did not see this happen. (If I was asking because I saw something like that, I would have mentioned it in the post.) But I was not able to find this documented somewhere either. I think that it is useful to know whether this can happen or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Who is the Community user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)

Comment: Your answer lies within the [first answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/173052) , but can also directly go and read [OK, Now Define “Answered”](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/)

Comment: @FallenAngel In the links you provided I read: *Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention.* And: *Unanswered questions have no answers with upvotes (or accepted).* So based on this you are saying, that Community user bumps all unanswered questions, including the closed ones?

Comment: No. A closed question do not have a chance to got an answer. But beyond that, a closed question is the question that do not fit to the community guidelines, it do not add anything to the community even if it got upvotes or new answers. That are valid for un-closed questions.

Comment: *A closed question do not have a chance to got an answer* It can get an answer before it is closed. I have seen loads of such questions. *A closed question is the question that do not fit to the community guidelines.* There are other reasons for closing (for example duplicates.) But more importantly, I do not see an answer to the question I have posted in the links you suggested @FallenAngel. (Maybe I am missing something obvious or I did not read them carefully enough.)

Comment: That is my guess from the final line *So if you were wondering why the number of “unanswered” questions just went from barely a hundred to nearly two thousand, this is why* . AFAIK, closed questions do not listed in the *unanswered* section (except ones that looked open but in fact are closed, but that is a cache issue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The community user do not bump closed/locked questions. Also, it does **not** bump open questions with **no answers at all**.

> Note that the posts eligible for bumping have gone at least 30 days
>   with no activity, have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring
>   more than that, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be locked or
>   closed).

([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/187824))

Comment: Actualy, question got to have 0 score or more to be bumped: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018/moderator-clean-up-of-abandoned-poor-quality-questions/2099#comment7420_2099

Comment: I did not know that questions with no answers are not bumped. Apart from your link, it is mentioned also here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217884/community-user-does-not-bump-questions-that-never-had-an-answer It is good to know this, so thanks for mentioning that as well.