# Are edited questions bumped to the front page?

Tags: support, edits, bump

I got a warning for multiple edits to a question on *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)*, stating "Editing posts, even deleted ones, bumps them to the front page which takes precious front page real estate, and can be disruptive to others." I didn't find any mention of an issue with multiple edits in the code of conduct. If this is an issue, it should be included in the code of conduct.

However, I did not see this occur. After making an edit, I sometimes went back to the main mathematics questions page and also to questions tagged "finite-fields", and did not see my question getting bumped to the front page. The question has a score of zero, which may be the reason, based on this 12 year old question:

[Are edited questions no longer bumped to the front page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62261/384979)

There's also this question from 11 years ago:

[Allow non-bumping minor edits, but review them on /review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122567/384979)

Comment: Mathematics.SE has over 1950 tags, and a high activity rate; does anyone pay attention to the front page? What is the default setting for tagged pages, active or newest (mine is set to newest, but I don't recall setting it). Since that 12 year old question, have there been any other suggestions for monitoring / reviewing edits? Wikipedia has a good solution: each member can create a watch list for articles or other pages to get notified of any edits or new content, along with a method to see the actual changes.

Comment: I'm not that active on Mathematics.SE, 17 answers, 6 questions, as opposed to my activity at Stack Overflow, 1739 answers, 8 questions (26.8k rep). This is part of the reason I was unaware that editing would bump questions on Stack Exchange, in addition to never seeing my question on Mathematics.SE front page or bumped on the finite-field page.

Comment: Is there any tool that would allow someone to create | edit | format a question that others could read and provide feedback in a cyclic manner so that only a single final edit is done to an actual question or answer? Essentially a publicly viewable version of a preview.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they are. There might be several reasons why you don't see them:

- The homepage is cached (for a minute or so) - if you refresh too early, you don't see the changes. On the contrary, if you refresh too late on an active site, it might already be superseded by other edits or new posts.
- You ignore one of the tags on the question (and have chosen to hide those questions, instead of merely graying them out).
- The question has a score of [-4 or lower](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62261/are-edited-questions-no-longer-bumped-to-the-front-page/62262#comment148393_62262), which hides it from the homepage.
- On Stack Overflow and Mathematics Stack Exchange, the homepage is personalized based on the tags you're active in. If you edit your own posts, you're likely to see them, but if you [edit other users' posts en-masse](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/9d954d34385d2ac2597bbe864466259f) you might not notice.

Most (all?) of those reasons don't apply to the tag page, so regarding

> and also to questions tagged "finite-fields"

Are you sure you have the 'Active' tab selected, rather than e.g. 'Newest'? That may also happen when you click the 'Questions' page in the left navigation:

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1667/discussion-on-answer-by-glorfindel-are-edited-questions-bumped-to-the-front-page); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.