# Do pending edits get bumped to the front page?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, bump, homepage

If a low-rep user makes an edit which needs to be approved, does it get bumped to front-page? I hardly ever visit main page (am on [unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)), so I wouldn't have noticed.

Comment: you should see a number in the top bar (between your badges and review) if there are edits for you to approve. I was hoping to find documentation on it, but I can't right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pending edits only get bumped up to the top page if they are approved, see [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/152859) for more details.

In short suggested edit is approved when one of these happens:

1. Author of the post approves
2. Diamond moderator approves
3. Two users with full edit privilege (usually 2K) approve
4. One user with full edit privilege choose to Improve the edit and tick the "this edit was helpful"