# Thread Activity

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can cause my question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped)

When a post has new comments or voting is it moved to the top of the active questions list?

Comment: and the answer is no.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I got down voted for posting in the wrong place, even though I can't post in the right place.  Quite a system.

Comment: I asked because I have had some fairly old questions down-voted (anonymously).

Comment: You are not banned. There is no red "user suspended" stripe on your profile. Are you getting an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: When I clicked ask a question I got a page that said  "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more."

Comment: The link location for ask is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: That's the quality monitering systems kicking in. As you had two question heavily downvoted and a one closed the system has prevented you from asking any more questions (which on a meta site is not the best idea. Also, I though the goo.gl link was removed).

Comment: @dbasnett your IP may have been banned but your account was not (as @Popular mentioned), I'm going to edit your question so as not to derail the actual question with account discussion

Comment: @tombull89 - It has been almost a year.  If I can't ask questions how can I possibly get more points?  Comments only?  The questions I was down-voted so heavily were about points in this game.

Comment: In light of @Daniels edit I have edited my answer.

Comment: Seems like something you could have easily tested for yourself... Or searched for an existing question that already answered it. Your choice.

Comment: Me and Steve Jobs.  What are you going to do with us stupid users... :)  I used to do help desk stuff and inevitably you had to ask if it was plugged in. It was amazing how often it wasn't.  I made sure they knew how stupid they were.

Answer (score 7):

Comment and votes do not bump a question, only answer and edits do.

You can go and edit your questions to raise them to the front page again, although this is unfortunately likely to result in more downvotes to you.

Comment: The OP is not banned. There's no red stripe on his/her profile.

Comment: I should have been more succinct.  I can participate (comment), just not ask questions, which makes this answer "We're a Question and Answer site" amusing.

Comment: @dbasnett - It makes it accurate.  If this were a forum you would be **banned** and not reading this :)  Also nothing is stopping you from **CONTRIBUTING** in the form of answers.

Comment: Why would I be banned?  Hadn't tried answers, I quit coming to this site since last July.

Comment: you were the one that said "now I have been banned" - but you havent. "Banned" is the complete and utter destruction of the account, while the quaility filter (which you have triggered) prevents any questions being asked. You can still comment (and maybe answer, I am not sure).

Comment: also, not trying to be petty, if you quit the site, why'd you come back?

Comment: For participating at all today I just received some new down votes for the questions from a year ago.  Wow!

Comment: I have answered your question. It is up to you to accept or not.

Comment: @tombull89 - SO moved my question.  I wanted to vent about anonymous down votes (again) of old posts at SO.  And look Ma' it happens here too.

Comment: "I have answered your question. It is up to you to accept or not."  I would have voted to close this, but I can't.

Comment: @dbasnett - you may get better results from your interactions here if you stop thinking of yourself as a martyr who is being singled out and,  you know, contributed or something.  Coming back to complain is probably not going to garner you a lot of positive attention.

Comment: I had a legitimate question.  The page that popped up when I tried to ask the question wasn't exactly user friendly, so I mistakenly thought I was banned.  I may not be alone in the inability to ask questions here ("being singled out") but how would I know.  These xOverflow sites are just a place to ask / receive help.  Down-votes should be banned, and if not that, then anonymous down-votes should be.

Comment: @dbasnett - Then feel free to start your own series of sites with that ethos.  That's not how it works here, and you have already gotten more than your money's worth for your contributions I think.

Comment: @JNK - Thanks.  I didn't know that.

Comment: and those down votes for year old posts just keep rolling in :)  Don't draw attention to yourself, don't draw attention to yourself, don't draw attention to yourself, don't draw attention to yourself...

Comment: Roughly 6% of the questions here (meta) are tagged with a vote related tag.  On some of the older sites I participate in the number is < .01%.  Most(all I think) of them only allow up-voting.  See you in about a year...