# Do questions have a second chance on the homepage?

Tags: discussion, questions, homepage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

I wonder if there is a kind of cycling mechanism about the way the questions show up on the home page...

If my question has already had its Moment of Glory on the homepage (that lasts 1,0244 sec. ;-) and has had 3 views during that time, Is there any chance that my little question will be shown a second or a third time to the largest audience ?

EDIT FOR THOSE WHO DOESN'T READ QUESTIONS (Except the title) : I'm asking about the SE engine. Not what I (personally) can do to make my question to the top page : "Is the code that build the home page recycle old questions?"

Comment: Edit your question and make the title really shine.

Comment: OMG, but this is not the same question. I didn't ask if I can do something to attrack people on my question. I have asked if the SE engine do some kind of recycling and shows old questions on the home page... sigh.

Comment: Place a bounty...

Comment: @Pierre See [What can cause my question to be bumped?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped) then

Answer (score 4):

Editing or retagging a question, and getting answers bump a question to the homepage.

See [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

Answer (score 3):

If your question didn't receive an upvoted answer, there's a tiny chance that the question will be bumped to the front page automatically (by the [Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user) after some time.