# Why answered questions are reactivated?

Tags: discussion, activity-summary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can cause my question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped)

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884550/converting-html-to-plain-text-in-php-for-e-mail) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401349/how-to-avoid-conflict-between-jquery-and-prototype) question on the questions page.

At first I was shocked to see that these questions showed "2 mins ago" with 6K views, and the question too is not challenging. I wondered: how come a simple question gets 6K views with 5 answers and 7 votes in just 2 mins? But then I opened the question and found that the question was asked 2 years ago and it was already answered years back.

So: why were these answered questions placed on the questions page again today? This is not the first time, I found many questions of such kind in Stack Exchange sites. If unanswered questions or challenging questions are re-posted there will be a use. Can anybody tell me why and how these questions get reactivated?

Comment: The magic word is "bump" or "[bumped](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=bumped)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as re-posting. Questions and answers are posted and remain posted till eternity. However, they can be deleted and be undeleted.

Questions are reactivated by an edit to it or to one of its answers, by a new answer, or by a bounty.

The why is inherent: edits are made to fix up style or grammar, or because the post needs revision due to recent changes on the topic. In short: the reason is to improve the stack exchange content.

Answer (score 5):

A user added their answer to both questions. That is possible, and late answers are in fact welcome, seeing as things can change and a "more correct" answer might come up over time.

Comment: (And now I've edited the question to make your 2nd paragraph even more confusing. I'd never do that to Pekka, but well, a Rep Mining Corporation needs to work for their reputation! And yes, you edited after my upvote, so I *could* revert that! `;-)`)

Comment: @Arjan wow, things really get tougher when you go corporate! But then, we have lawyers now. And a PR department. And thugs. Be careful!

Comment: I learned two new words since you started your mining corporation: *smelting* (which I figured was a typo for *melting*, but I was wrong) and *thugs* (which I hoped was a typo for *hugs*, but, no again). So, I am now facing thugs who can smelt? *Dear Mister VP, I am very sorry for any trouble I might have caused! Please don't hurt me, take the wife and kids!*

Comment: @Arjan bwahaha! Running an evil corporation has its perks.