# What events result in 'bumping' of a question?

Tags: discussion, bump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can cause my question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped)

The obvious are edits and new answers, however sometimes I notice something else is triggering the bumping. I suspect casting a (not final) close vote also does it and reveals the name of the close-voter on the main page (`2m ago by Foo Barrer`). Is that intended? Or do I misunderstand what's happening?

Comment: There is a random element that bumps questions to the front page too (so questions that haven't been in the spotlight for a while can get their chance).

Comment: @Oded in that case the little label in the right says `Community`, right?

Comment: @LevLevitsky Yeah, it will. Do you have a link to the question that prompted you to post this?

Comment: @AnnaLear I do, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179391/regex-preg-replace-for-emoticons) it is. Is there a deleted answer? (it doesn't have to be spam, right? Sometimes people just delete their answers)

Comment: @LevLevitsky Yes, that's right. There's a self-deleted answer on that question. Also an edit that came after it. Looks like there are several kinds of activity still happening on that question that could bump it.

Comment: @AnnaLear Sure, it's just that I looked at the username at the homepage and couldn't find it anywhere when I opened the question. So, all possible reasons are listed here?

Comment: @LevLevitsky I *think* so. I'm sure someone will come to correct me if I'm wrong soon enough. :)

Comment: OK, thanks @Anna. Just wanted to know if I should check the tick now. Will give it some time then :)

Comment: How come the FAQ question not come out in top search results for "what bumps a question"?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, casting a close vote doesn't bump the question.

Posting an answer or making an edit to the question (or any answer) does, though. The Community user will also bump questions without upvoted answers periodically to try and get more eyes on them.

Sometimes you'll also see a question that was bumped by an answer that was later deleted, so if you don't have 10,000 rep it looks like the questions was bumped for no reason.

Comment: Also, reopening a closed question gives it a bump.

Comment: _"The Community user will also bump questions without upvoted answers periodically to try and get more eyes on them."_ Is this still true? I'm pretty sure [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169255/mentioning-programmers-stackexchange-in-the-stackoverflow-faq) isn't getting bumped. Is the answer with -1 throwing off the algorithm?

Comment: @HonestAbe The question has to be at least a month old and even then not everything gets bumped at once if there are a lot of unanswered questions.