# Add section about when to use Programmers SE in the Stack Overflow FAQ

Tags: discussion, faq-update-request

Recently [a question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569751/can-i-release-code-that-modifies-a-java-class) was closed as off-topic because it was a license issue question. This is fine, but what is irksome is that I did the following before posting.

1. I read [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions), where it states four distinct questions that are relevant, one of which is `* practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession`
2. I did a search for license questions, of which I found many, some closed but many not.

This led me to believe this was a valid question to ask.

Now to the point. If this happens often maybe there should be one more example added to the FAQ in the section "[If your question would be of interest to](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)" for Programmers SE, where it is appropriate to ask these questions, [Programmers FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq).
Something along the lines of

- Code style, conceptual programming issues, or license questions, ask on Programmers SE

Comment: Are licensing questions on-topic for Programmers? And if we did this, why would we stop at just Programmers? What about all of the sites in the migrate/off-topic list?

Comment: Let's be honest - how many people really read the FAQ?

Comment: I was a little surprised @Andrew but [they are](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq)... apparently

Comment: When to try asking on Programmers.SE if you're on SO: never.

Comment: Given that we already have a bulleted list of suggested sites that are closely related, I think this would be a good addition to the FAQ.  Also, I'm adding `licensing` to my list of tags to kill on SO.

Comment: I answered a question just like this recently [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174134/158605). To summarize, I think that is a bad idea simply because Programmers already closes over 50% of their questions, so you would likely just flood them with low-quality content and be sending people off to have a bad experience on another SE site. I think Programmers needs to sort out how they communicate their actual site scope to new users first before we start sending them users en masse from SO's FAQ (here's a hint: their scope is not programmers).

Comment: Please, please, do [tag:certification] first @bill... it kills me. There are never enough close voters in there...

Comment: But their scope is licensing questions, and higher level concepts.  Why not mention this in another very related site

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Adding it to my list.  :)

Comment: I think people's attention starts to wane when they encounter instructions to read another FAQ in the FAQ they are currently reading. There's only so many FAQs a person can read in a day, and the probable end result is that they'll just post their question on the SO, then replicate it on Programmers if it gets closed.

Comment: @greedybuddha Why not mention that cooking questions can go on [cooking](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/) or that bicycle related questions can go on [Bicycles](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/)  Each site defines it's own scope; not it's scope and every other site's scope as well.

Comment: @Servy Because we don't get a lot of cooking or bicycling questions on Stack Overflow.  We do get a lot of software licensing questions though, and there is a place where those are welcome.

Comment: Its very different Servy, here there is a great deal of overlap and therefore it would be useful to be able to draw a line between the two. You don't need to do that with coding and cooking ;)

Comment: Why did you delete your most recent question?

Comment: I found an exact duplicate. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170873/hide-upvotes-and-downvotes-totals-after-another-click?rq=1

Comment: @greedybuddha You could have closed it instead of deleting outright

Comment: Good to know! I just figured why leave a duplicate lying around.