# Question on SO is not active even though it didn't get an answer accepted

Tags: support

I find some of my questions asked on SO get inactive even though I didn't accept an answer.
Since I am looking for better answers or for other reasons. While I find some questions which popup in SO's interesting tab which are asked many days ago (*few even 6months old*), have an accepted/unaccepted answer and are still shown as active.

I don't find my questions shown in the active questions tab even though they have unaccepted answers. Why is it happening with my questions? Please let me know.

**These are my questions which are shown inactive:**

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136204/difference-between-accessing-a-website-using-local-host-and-ip-address
2. [Create a Directory using Directory.CreateDirectory( ) that gives a warning message when trying to delete or rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947631/create-a-directory-using-directory-createdirectory-that-gives-a-warning-messa)
3. [Application that indents an unindented code in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922079/application-that-indents-an-unindented-code-in-c-sharp)

**This is a example question which is still active:**
- [Are there any IoC frameworks that do not use JIT compilation that support interception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006446/are-there-any-ioc-frameworks-that-do-not-use-jit-compilation-that-support-interc)

Comment: Your questions are not inactive; they just are not *recently* active. The 'interesting' tab contents differ for each user. Also see [What can cause my question to be bumped?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578)

Comment: Questions show in the active tab when there was any activity on them (question edited, new answer posted, existing answer edited), it has nothing to do with the question having an accepted answer or not.

Comment: Many people ignore many tags. You seem to be using "exotic" tags so maybe this explain the low (in your opinion) amount of views.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to bump your question to the front page, you can do one or all of the following actions:

- Improve it by editing it.
- Put a bounty on it.
- Post a link on another site.
- Add comments to existing answers to ask for more information.

If the question has several answers but none of them is suitable, chances are the question is not 100% clear, so improving it is probably the way to go.

And don't forget that this is a free site. Other people are not required to answer, and you are not required to accept.

Comment: Editing the question does not bump it up.

Comment: @Happy yes it is. Where did you get this wrong information from?

Comment: I tried it, and my questions never got bumped up. Anyway, I don't care about this site any more, so it doesn't matter.