# Is it possible to bump a question?

Tags: support, bump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can cause my question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped)

If I asked a question and there were very few views after couple days and no answers, is it possible to bump it instead of duplicating itthat users will be able to see it again as new question?

Comment: What question are you talking about? I only see one question you asked 1 hour ago. Did you delete a previously asked question? If so, try not to do that. Do it often enough and you might run into a question ban.

Comment: @Bart I asked about a question in SO that didn't get any answers. what I could do in case of no answers in the next days.

Comment: Leave the questions there. Improve them if possible. Don't delete them though. That signals you have asked bad questions and could (from what I know) result in a ban if done often enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you edit a question, it's bumped to the front page.

Don't abuse the feature, but use to to clarify a question that hasn't gotten any responses.

You can also place a Bounty on your question if it hasn't received any attention.