# Why has every question on Webmasters been modified by Community?

Tags: support, community-user, specific-site

I just had a look through Webmasters briefly, and noticed that most questions on the [Unanswered tab](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=1&tab=votes) have been modified by Community:

[image]

Upon clicking [a question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35256/disqus-thread-migration-gotchas), Community isn't mentioned anywhere. Looking at [its timeline](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/posts/35256/timeline), there's no mention of it there either.

So why is Community modifying everything?

Comment: It just bumped those questions, as is not unusual for the Community user. As stated in its profile *"I do things like randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention"*

Comment: Is it appraisal time for the [community](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), looks like a lot of work!

Comment: @Bart That looks kinda ridiculous to a passer-by.

Comment: Yep, it causes some confusion from time to time. But hey, if it causes users to look at the question, job well done. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those look like the periodic auto-bumps.

The community user [occasionally bumps unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579) with a lot of views. The unanswered tab displays unanswered questions sorted by votes.

So there's likely to be a lot of overlap between the two.

Comment: Lots of views? Like the 67 views in my screenshot? :p Thanks for your answer though, I'll accept when I can.

Comment: It's relative to all the other unanswered questions. On a big site like SO, I've never seen a question with fewer than 2k views get bumped.

Comment: That is oddly backwards, you'd expect questions that *didn't* get enough views to need bumping.

Comment: @UphillLuge That argument is that the views are from people coming in from search engine traffic looking for an answer to the same question. But there isn't one. So the question is prioritized higher for auto-bumping to hope that it gets answered.

Comment: @UphillLuge If a question gets no answers and no views, it's most likely a bad question, but in such a way that nobody was willing to do anything about it.

Comment: You can't know it is a bad question until you view it :)  Bad title, maybe.