# Degrees of modification

Tags: discussion, active

Why is it that something as minor as retagging moves a question to the top of the [active list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active), but something as significant as adding a 500-character comment to a question doesn't?

Comment: Related: [What can cause my question to be bumped?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped)

Comment: Comments are not edits, but retags are.  Bumping is only triggered by making a change to a post.  Comment additions do not bump a post, because comments are directed at specific people, not the general user community.

Answer (score 3):

Because here at SE we don't care about comments.  The system seems to hate them with a passion.  They didn't even exist when the sites were first rolled out, but there was enough demand from users for them to be added.

The system works very hard to ensure that important information isn't in comments; it should be in posts.  The entire purpose of comments is to work to ensure the quality of the posts they comment on is improved.  Once they have succeeded at that goal they should be deleted.

Not bumping questions in the question list for comments is just one more way of indicating that comments aren't nearly as important as posts themselves.  If you have something truly important or valuable to say you should ensure that it makes it into a post somewhere (through appropriate means of course).

Comment: Damn, no good, lousy comments! Flag the lot of 'em! If you're a commenter, you're a bad person!.....Oh, wait.