# Is there a way to see how a recently modified question was modified?

Tags: support, question-lists

In the questions list, recently modified questions are moved to the top:

> [image]

That one says "modified 59 minutes ago Leon Bambrick".

Is there a way to easily find out what was modified?

For example, [for the above question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses), the process I went through was:

1. Visit the question.
2. Didn't see an edit on the question.
3. Looked for new answers, didn't notice any.
4. Looked through the question and all answers for new comments, didn't notice any.
5. Searched the page for the user name, "Leon", no results.
6. Double checked to make sure I didn't have to click "view all comments" anywhere (thus defeating find on page), then searched page again, no results.
7. Looked through one more time very closely and eventually found it, an edit to an answer:

> [image]

Is there another way to find out how a question was modified that isn't such an investigative journey?

Comment: Click directly on "modified 59 minutes ago"

Comment: [tag:feature-request] Ability to downvote own question out of shame.

Comment: Oh, re: step 4, [comments don't count as modifications](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183371/159251).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click directly on the "modified 59 minutes ago" link and it will take you straight to the modified post (the question or an answer).

(Unless the post has been deleted and you don't have the privileges required to see it.)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to ff524's answer about the "modified $TIME ago" link from the list view, there is a link in every question's sidebar to the most recent change:

[image]

The date portion of the "active" stat will jump you to whichever post was most recently modified (or posted).

The same caveat that ff524 mentioned applies here: the date does not take deletion into account, so if the last modification was to a removed post and you are unable to view deleted posts, the link will essentially just refresh the page.