# Community bot raking up abandoned questions

Tags: feature-request, review, community-user, bump

The Community bot frequently rakes up abandoned questions, I have come across a few, for example, [WD Elements 1042 usb 3.0 not recognized by Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/662686/wd-elements-1042-usb-3-0-not-recognized-by-windows-7)

Is it not better to put it in the review queue and help to be removed, since it is partially pertinent to the OP and there is no accepted answer. Also the OP has not answered the question, nor indicated as to the problem being solved.

Comment: Why are you assuming they are abandoned? Community is supposed to bump unanswered questions so that they have a second chance at being answered.

Comment: Something unanswered since an year can be considered abandoned I think. Or you might want to define what abandoned means.

Comment: Answer unaccepted and no answers posted by the OP himself.

Comment: Maybe for whatever reason, that answer didn't work for him. But i don't see why it needs to be removed - what if someone else has that problem?

Answer (score 4):

Perodically, the Community user bumps a question that meet certain criteria (no up voted answers).  The purpose of this is to stir up activity on the question - either votes for deserving overlooked answers, new answers, or sometimes the attention of the people who will act on it to cast a close vote or flag which kicks it into the review process.

Note that the votes and more answers are things that wouldn't be appropriate for a review queue (and there are suggestions that there are already too many review queues or that they aren't doing their job well enough already).

The front page itself is a form of review - it sheds light on the question to all (even those who don't visit /review).

Note that there is an automated script that *will* delete abandoned questions.  The [criteria for that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year) are:

- 30 days old
- no answers
- -1 score
- not locked

or

- older than 365 days old
- score of 0 (or 1 with a deleted owner)
- no answers
- not locked
- low view count
- less than 2 comments

For these questions, no /review is necessary and they will be automatically deleted.  The idea with community bouncing some of them (randomly) is on the off chance that they might get a good answer.  If it's not a good question, older than 30 days but younger than 365 days, a down vote is sufficient.

Related:

- [Community ♦ should discriminate more when bumping unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99672/)
- [What are the criteria for Community to bump a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238037/what-are-the-criteria-for-community-to-bump-a-question)
- [Why does a question appear as modified by the Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/why-does-a-question-appear-as-modified-by-the-community-user)
- [Anomalous community user activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43015/anomalous-community-user-activity)