# What does it mean if Community “asks” a question?

Tags: support, questions, community-user

Just scrolling through Stack Overflow, and saw this:

[image]

I looked in and the author who asked it wasn’t Community. What does this mean? The real asker’s profile picture was gray.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)

Comment: Can you link to the question this was?

Comment: So it’s who last made a change on the post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Community *can* actually ask a question, but it's rare. Here are some examples:

- [Sandbox archive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296077/sandbox-archive) (here on Meta Stack Exchange)
- [March 2019 Community Moderator Election](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380884/4751173) (on Meta Stack Overflow)

This is usually the results of a script run by Stack Exchange staff, and won't happen on main sites.

But usually it's something else. As [Jdrupal writes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341212/295232), it can [bump a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238037/295232); another possibility is a recent spam answer, where both the post and the account have been deleted. The community user will then 'own' the latest activity on the question as well.

Comment: What are the questions like?

Comment: Also, the users profile picture was gray. I will mention that.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn’t mean that Community wrote the question, it just means that Community made a change on that post.

Usually it’s because the post was bumped to the homepage, in order for it to get attention.