# Will undeleting my question cause it to appear in "newest questions"?

Tags: discussion, undelete, newest-questions

I posted a question on [Super User](http://superuser.com) a few days back on a weekend and it has received no responses/views.

Can I delete that question and undelete it again to make it appear in the "Newest Questions" feed?

Will undeleting a question make it appear in the newest questions feed?

Comment: Why would it? Undeleting it won't change the time it was originally posted at.

Comment: [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/262755)

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce Thank you for the link. That was pretty much what I was looking for. Just wasn't searching for it with the correct terms. I also referred to http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers. Thanks once again. Since I don't have enough reputation here to up vote your comment, I'm not doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. And 'bumping' posts like this would be a bit of a misuse of the site if it were possible.

If they question isn't getting any views / attention then that probably means the question itself isn't very good / clear. So best bet is to edit the the question itself to improve the quality, and make sure it's tagged appropriately. That will then push the question up to the top. That's the correct way to deal with these things.

If it's still not getting answers then perhaps people just don't know the answer. Constantly pushing it to the front of the queue isn't going to change things like that.

Comment: You could also place a bounty on it if you have sufficient reputation to do so.

Comment: FWIW, [deletion and undeletion don't bump](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped)

Comment: Also, don't forget that bumping puts the question at the top of the *active* list, not newest. The latter only goes by the original posting date.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had asked the question on a weekend late in the night. Probably just one of the reasons why my question got no views. Anyway, I have got my answer. Thank you.