# What does make Community user "modify" the post, besides bumping?

Tags: support, edits, community-user

There is a list of actions of the Community user in "his portfolio": [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)

However, I would like to know what all actions (besides the bumps) lead to the question being "modified by Community". If there are no such actions, can someone higher up clarify, please?

Comment: *all actions that lead to a question being "modified by Community"* are listed in the post you've linked, quoting: *Questions with at least 30 days of no activity, at least one answer scoring zero, and no answers scoring above that. Questions that are locked or closed will not be bumped. The Community User will only bump a maximum of one question per hour.*  Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped

Comment: @nicael I'm lost now. Do you speak about all actions (including the edits by whoever and stuff like that) or only the bumps?

Comment: The second link also includes the information on bumping by Community user: *Questions are picked randomly from the top-viewed inactive questions. The number of unanswered questions bumped per hour depends on the site: 4 per hour on Stack Overflow, 1 per hour on Meta, and 2 per hour on Super User and Server Fault. The default for a new site is 1 per hour.*

Comment: @nicael I know about bumping. I ask about the other actions of the CU. Is my question unclear?

Comment: In both my comments, I was referring your last sentence.

Comment: @nicael There are other actions than bumps that lead to "modified by Community", for instance spam deletion is "modified by community" AFAIK.

Comment: Nope, I'd say it's not true.

Comment: @nicael Right, the spammer's name sits there. I'll clarify the question, thanks.

Comment: The fact that the poster name with "modified by" remains on the homepage after the post is deleted doesn't relate to the fact that post could be spam.

Comment: @zondo Yep, mentioned that in my answer :)

Comment: Yes @Zondo, that's what he meant.

Comment: @nicael: Sorry, I didn't notice who wrote the answer until after I posted my comment.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sorry for the mess, I realized that I actually confused myself and included 2 questions in the post (one general, one for "modified by Community"), so I cleaned it up.

Comment: All good, next time just don't forget to edit the title as well... :-)

Comment: Bad me. /slaps my right hand with the left hand and vice versa

Answer (score 6):

As the linked post explains, the Community also gets the credit for the approved edits by anonymous users. You will also see "modified by Community", but in this case, *literally* modified :)

Centuries ago, when [the duplicate notice was inserted right in the question body](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/148066/2), it did also lead to the question being "modified by Community".

Also, if the staff decides to do the repeated edit to all of the posts on the site, it attracts the Community user. Looks like the timestamps of those events are merged into the timestamps of the previous edit events to that post, so as not to clutter the homepage. E.g.

> [image]

[Here's the modified post](/posts/161869/revisions), and [the edit which shared it's timestamp with the Community edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/161869/2).

Comment: Who does question merges?

Comment: No, I meant, if a moderator merges two questions, what will show as the last action? Won't it also be "modified by Community"?

Comment: @yo' I believe merging does leave no timestamp at all, similar to closing / locking.