# When the Community user bumps questions, could it say "bumped" rather than "modified"?

Tags: feature-request, community-user, bump

I just noticed this

[image]

I opened the question to see what the modification was. But I saw that neither the question nor the answer had been modified recently. I was about to post on meta to find out what had happened, but I checked the revision history instead. There, I noticed that it said "**Bumped by Community user**". Turns out it's a [cool feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/321647) to bring exposure to certain questions (those that fit certain criteria which suggest they may need exposure.)

So, in the text from the screenshot above, could the text be changed from "modified" to "bumped"?
[image]

Or maybe some other, more suitable word. But not "modified" since it is in fact *not* being modified.

Comment: "marked as duplicate by Community♦ 1"... I should have known better than to mess with the Community user....