# Why doesn't the "marked as duplicate" notice include the user who voted to close?

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

In [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283942/321647), I got a notice that my question was a duplicate, and I clicked a button to confirm that it was.

But it says that only the Community user marked the question. Wouldn't it also include the user who initially voted to close? So shouldn't there be at least one username on the notice in addition to the Community user?

Or did the user just flag, not vote, and thus was not on the notice? Do I still get that "That solved my problem" button when someone simply flags?

Comment: If you don't agree the question is a duplicate, edit the question, to reflect that fact.  People might not agree with you but that is still a required step.

Comment: Sorry I was confused.

Comment: @Ramhound OK, no problem. We can do a comment cleanup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No one else ever voted to close your question. There was a user who *flagged* it as a duplicate, which is why you saw the notice and why you were allowed to confirm it as a duplicate. The Community user takes credit for the closure since the normal process of closing a question is essentially being overridden.

Users who flag do not ever show up in that notice, partly because there can be an unlimited number of flags for closure on a question, but only five actual votes for closure. If we showed them all, that list could be infinitely long. As well, users who flag do not have full close voting privileges. Their flag has no actual effect on the closing of the question and only brings it to the attention of other users who *can* do something. No matter how many flags a question accumulates, it will never be closed because of them.

Also of note: the behavior you experienced is not the dupehammer. The dupehammer is a special privilege given to users who have received the gold tag badge in a tag used on that question. When it is used, you'll see a gold circle next to their name to indicate it. The confirmation box you saw is a special tool shown only to the owner of the question, allowing them to quickly confirm that a duplicate did in fact solve their problem and close their question without the need of further users to cast close votes.