# Do not all answers bump a question?

Tags: support, answers, bump

The question [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped) says that answers will bump a question.

However, recently I noticed some older questions not being bumped after I answered them.

One example is [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/105846/sqli-can-i-extract-a-mysql-data-without-knowing-columns-name/135110).

I'm wondering if this is a bug, or if there are criteria for when not to bump a question, such as it's age, downvotes (the linked answer for example does note an exception for edits, but not for answers), existing close votes, and so on.

<sub>Edit: After asking this question, I upvoted the question I linked, and it got bumped, suggesting that downvotes may restrict bumps. I would still be interested in a general answer though.</sub>

Comment: Did the question have a score of -4 when you answered it?

Comment: That was bumped...

Comment: @randal'thor It did, so that may be it (although I think I remember answering old questions with less or no downvotes, so there may be some other restrictions as well? I'm not sure though). If that is the case, it would probably be a good idea to update the linked question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**All questions with a score of -3 or higher get bumped whenever a new answer is posted or an edit is made to the question or any of its answers.**

In [the case you link to](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/105846/sqli-can-i-extract-a-mysql-data-without-knowing-columns-name/135110), you answered the question when it had a score of -4, so it didn't get bumped to the top of the front page. After you upvoted it to a score of -3, it now *does* appear on [the list of recently active questions on the front page of Sec.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/?tab=active):

[image: screenshot]