# How to stop the Community user from dredging up old questions over and over?

Tags: feature-request, community-user, bump

So here is [an example of a question that *Community* has reposted to the DSP SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/35739/how-to-find-the-dtft-of-unit-step-with-1n-scalar-multiplied).

This question has been clearly answered, but no check mark perhaps because the OP has moved on.  But the Community user will dredge this question up again sometime in the future and will again and again until the OP marks the answer as acceptable, which may never happen.

Is there a way that people can vote to "close" the question or some other appropriate operation that will tell the system that the question is answered?  It need not put in the check mark nor award 15 rep to the person answering. But we will get tired of these questions being repeatedly resurrected because the OP hadn't declared them answered.

This usually happens on trivial questions or those that are malformed or otherwise useless.  It'd be nice not to have to see them again.

Comment: Ironically, the community user seems to like bumping this question.

Comment: i want to deliberately not check mark either answer so as to demonstrate this irony.

Comment: I mean; it's technically not 'bumping' the answer. It edited an http:// link to https://. The bot doesn't bump any question with a positive score, so accepting an answer wouldn't make a difference

Answer (score 16):

You can stop Community from bumping a question by:

- Upvoting that answer, if it merits it.  An answer with a positive score prevents the bump.
- Answering it yourself, if the current answer is inadequate.  If yours is good, somebody will presumably upvote it and then Community will stop bumping it.
- Downvoting the question if it deserves it.  The Community user doesn't bump negatively-scored questions.  Maybe the reason it's not getting upvoted answers is that it's a poorly-asked question.
- Closing the question, if it's not now a suitable question for the site.  This can particularly be the case with old questions, where the site scope might have since changed.
- Deleting the question, if it's *really* junk and unsalvageable.

If you're not sure what to do about a question that's getting unwelcome bumps, start a discussion on your meta or in your site's chat room about how to improve the question and/or answers.

See [the FAQ entry for bumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/162102) for more information.

Comment: Or vote down the question if it has a score of 0 (negatively scored questions aren't bumped)

Answer (score 13):

Except it's not answered.  There is *an* answer, but it has no upvotes at all.  Nobody has found it useful, and it hasn't been accepted.

Without any postively scored answer or an accept from the asker, Community will continue bumping it in hopes of it getting more attention.  If the answer is useful, upvote it, and it will stop doing so.

Comment: okay, i'll upvote the stupid answer.  (the answer is fine, but the question is stupid.)  will that make it go away?  what if the question is dumb and no answer deserved an upvote?  why can't we just make these trivial questions go away?

Comment: If it's not off-topic, then it's a valid question.  If you don't like it, downvote it.  Once it hits -4 votes, it's hidden from the front page, and community will still bump it, but you won't see it.