# Is there a way to filter out all "Community" bumps?

Tags: support, community-user, bump, question-lists

Do we really need Community pushing 3 year old posts to the top just because the OP didn't select an answer?

Why do I have to go to "hot" posts to get all the recents?

Comment: You're not seeing it because the post author hasn't evaluated the quality of the answer(s), you're seeing it because *no one in the community* has evaluated the quality of the answer(s).

Comment: My point is, "Community" should not push it to the top just because an answer has not been chosen.

Comment: Yes, I understand that you don't like it, I'm just ensuring you understand what it's actually doing, and why it's doing it, because your statement that it's based on the question author giving feedback indicates that you aren't.

Comment: It's not that an answer hasn't been chosen. It's that an answer hasn't been _voted on_. What to see fewer community bumps? Vote on answers.

Comment: No, there's no such way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop the Community user from dredging up old questions over and over?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288652/how-to-stop-the-community-user-from-dredging-up-old-questions-over-and-over) - the comments to that answer are your answer, vote up or down an answer there; after an upvote it won't be bumped, after four downvotes it will be *hidden* but still bumped. --- Do your work (everyone one on that site), vote correctly.

Answer (score 7):

I think that Community bumping of old unanswered questions (including questions with answers that have no votes) is one of the most valuable functions provided by the Stack Exchange developers.

Rather than simply deleting such questions, or leaving them to stagnate on a site, it re-surfaces them to give the community a chance to say whether they want to:

- answer them (best outcome for good questions)
- upvote them if they are worth keeping
- downvote them if not (this pushes them towards the Roomba for automatic deletion).

Comment: Thanks. I will just downvote them from now on. 