# Let us edit comments if it's the last one on the question/answer

Tags: feature-request, comments

I get that editing a comment when someone has replied to it could cause a lot of confusion, but if it's still the last on the question/answer we should be able to edit it.  For instance, today I commented and realized when it was too late that I forgot to use the @username so the person would get informed.  Or what if I posted a comment when irritated or even when not irritated, looked at it again 15 minutes later, and realized it sounded angry when I didn't mean it too.  It's true I could delete and repost, but if it's only one sentence that got messed up that seems like overkill.  Also, the person who asked the question would get 2 messages for practically the same comment.  I think we should be able to do this.

Comment: What do you mean "the last comment". This network has been around more than a decade, what's the advantage in me going back to a comment I posted twelve years ago and being able to edit it, when it's probably been deleted in the meantime anyhow and the person at whom it was directed hasn't logged-in for ten years?

Comment: By the last comment, I mean no one has posted a comment after it, so there is no chance that your editing the comment could make a later comment obsolete.  For instance right now this comment is the last comment.  If you reply, however, it wont be anymore.  Also, I'm not referring to twelve year old comments, I'm reffering to a couple hours.

Comment: What's wrong with the 5 minute rule (and basic proofreading of one's comments)?

Comment: sometimes you just don't notice things until you see it with fresh eyes later.  Also 5 minutes just isn't long enough imo.

Comment: To add (maybe this should have been a part of my last comment, but alas, too late), why shouldn't the individual strive to get into good habits regarding expressing themself on the network, reviewing their work, and increasing the speed at which they spot their own mistakes/omissions? Should the network promote a failure to adapt and learn? (Serious question, there are those who - for various reasons are stuck in their behaviours), What are the deeper psychological reasons for identifying those people and allowing flexibility, without promoting slowing everyone-else's learning down?

Comment: "without promoting slowing everyone-else's learning down?"  No offense, but I don't think it makes any sense to want a feature to "teach people to check their comments before posting."  People make mistakes, and have lives outside of stackexchange.  I think we all need to chillax a little.

Comment: @millard - "forgot to use the '@'username so the person would get informed. " - You are aware that even if you forgot to ping somebody, they are notified of your response, especially if they are the author of the contribution.

Answer (score 4):

### Forget to @ someone?

Hit the edit button and add it back in.

### Regret posting the comment?

I hate to be informal, but that's what the delete button is there for, brother.

---

I understand what you're asking for, but I don't understand why your arguments suggest needing what you're asking for.

We already have the ability to easily handle the cases you raise.

If you really need to edit your comment and it's too late, delete it and post an updated version.

Seriously, it takes considerably lesser effort than that which would go into implementing this feature.

It's a great idea, but I'd rather see the team working on other stuff, given that we can already work around the proposed issues without much deliberation.

Comment: SO/SE documentation says there are no guarantees about whether a notification is sent if an @ is edited into or out of a comment.

Answer (score 3):

> Also, the person who asked the question would get 2 messages for practically the same comment.

The [other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366841/369802) already addressed how you can edit your comment to @someone/delete the existing comment. But I want to write a bit about why the particular bit of reasoning I quoted above is a bad idea for this feature request too.

While not getting a notification when someone only corrects a typo may be nice... allowing last comments to be edited without anyone getting any type of notification would be open to a lot of abuse as well. Unlike [a lot of actions on posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/369802), including editing, comments do not 'bump' posts. And the [follow feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/369802) at this moment doesn't notify of edited comments either. So a last comment could be edited into something totally inappropriate, without even the OP of a post/the person the comment is @replying to getting a notification and a signal to flag the inappropriate comment. There's just too little chance for community moderation with this feature.

I'd rather have one notification too many  than have a feature that allows inappropriate comments to fly under the radar like that.

Comment: Re "you can edit your comment to @someone/delete the existing comment"" SO/SE documentation says there are no guarantees about whether a notification is sent if an @ is edited into or out of a comment. So one has to delete & repost one's comment to add an @.