# Is there another Stack Overflow website for machine learning/artificial intelligence topics?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

- It seems that Stack Overflow is more concerned about programming techniques and coding skills (which is a good thing!)..
- But I am asking if anyone knows another "Stack Overflow"-like site, but which is mainly concerned about Machine Learning and AI?

BTW: I have asked this question after nearly a week without an answer for [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749498/reinforcement-learning-with-neural-networks)

Comment: You're looking for StackExchange.

Comment: Well, even if there were such a site, it's hard to imagine it having the "critical mass effect" that SO has.  I mean, how many machine learning junkies are going to be out there feverishly clicking F5 all night waiting for the next AI question?

Comment: 11 close votes and not closed. WTH?

Comment: @paxdiablo: It looks like there's a problem with migration. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49125/is-the-closing-migrating-feature-broken

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/ZDI3OWRmOTAt Uhh... what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is timely! See this article: [ReadWriteWeb](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/stackoverflow_business_funding.php), under "Plans for the Future".

> Spolsky says that future sites will be rolled out through an automated process wherein a number of people will propose a site, then debate the ground-rules for content on the site and then gather a core group of experts to commit to the site. Once an algorithm has determined that a critical mass has been built on a topic, then a new site will open up on StackOverflow's own servers.

Amazing progress, by the way, for Stack Overflow. I'm happy to see this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a proposal for something similar [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5551/proposal-for-game-ai-se).