# Link to open a random unanswered question

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

I'd like to have a link to open a random unanswered question (questions with interesting tags should be opened with higher probability).

Just so it *could* happen one answers a question that otherwise would be at page 13 and never would have been spotted.

Comment: Jon Skeet [beat me to it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5551/random-question-button/5552#5552). Oh well...

Comment: Nice idea! ----