# Random unanswered question feature

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Random question button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5551/random-question-button)

I think a "give me a random unanswered question" button would be fun. Probably a random answered question button would be fun, too.

Comment: Also, on Stack Overflow, the homepage is [kind of randomly ordered](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/): *We also mix in a few random questions from the last 3,000 — 10% (9) for logged in users and 20% (18) for anonymous users.*

Comment: (But, as this has been migrated: the homepage on Programmers might be different.)