# Feature Request: Random Page

Tags: feature-request

I've always wanted to have a function that would allow the user to navigate to a *random* page on a certain site, that one might observe a question and see if one could furnish any degree of usefulness to that question. This seems possible (easy, at that). I'm not entirely sure how to suggest a feature request, but I might think this would be the way...

Comment: Do you assume that a person to use your feature is a jack of all trades, and a Leonardo da Vinci rolled in one?

Comment: @DeerHunter I'm not entirely sure as to your objection (your comment isn't _too_ clear), I believe I did say that it would be on a _certain_ _s_ite, and that your objection is that the feature would be a random page on a _random_ _s_ite; this is not what I meant. I merely meant that the feature would be bound within an arbitrary cite.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien: Surely you mean "site".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Am I using the wrong term? I mean "site" as in `xxxxxx.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: While I like the intent, the problem on some sites like SO is that you'll mostly get homework dumps, tl;dr debugging dumps, and "URGNT PLZ HALP, DUE IN 2 HOURS".

Comment: @ConorO'Brien: Yes, so that's a "site". There is no noun "cite" (other than an as informal shortening of "citation"). And yes this is how you do feature requests! :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ohhhhhh I see. I fixed that. And thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: Since this question is a duplicate, I posted [my random bookmarklet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245987/259867) under the original question.

Answer (score 2):

While this could be amusing, it would be a much better use of your spare time if you'd peruse the *review queues*, which are specifically populated with pages that really need your attention.

There are too many questions, at least on Stack Overflow, for a random question delivery to have anything but a vanishingly small probability of resulting in any action that would be either beneficial for the site as a whole, or entertaining for you.

Comment: I see your point, as to the fact it wouldn't be beneficial to the whole. Though, if one truly did strive to answer the unanswered, it could be the case that one might find an unanswered question at the bottom of the question feed...

Comment: @ConorO'Brien: If you click "unanswered" on the front page there are _plenty_ to choose from!